# JPA. Cast the field of @Entity in sql select

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have jpa entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class Document
...
@Column
private String docNumber;
...
```

And used JpaSpecificationExecutor to get result from DB:

```
Page<Document> findAll(@Nullable Specification<Document> spec, Pageable pageable)
```

In this case, spring-data-jpa make select like this:

```
select document0_."doc_number" from document
```

Can I tune jpa entity for select column with cast to int (perfectly, to other entity field):

```
select cast(document0_."doc_number" as int4) from document
```

It's needed, because in one case from many I get sql-query where `select distinct` used with `order by cast(document0_."doc_number" as int4)` and PostgreSQL return ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list.

Comment: No that's not possible if you want to return an Entity. Do you really need the entity in that case or would a DTO work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `spring-data-jpa` uses Hibernate as JPA engine, you can use Hibernate's [@Formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) annotation:

```
@Formula("cast('doc_number' as int4)")
private int docNumberAsInt4;
```

I haven't test it though.